# Going through the list in a specific way

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words and my input is one of the words in the first half of the list (in this case, this list is a german song). Now I take the lenght of this word and jump this the length of this word in list, f.e. first word in the list is "Es" and the length is 2. Now we count from "Es" 2 times and we land by word "zwei". I should go through this list and check if the word appears again in the second half of the list.

I tried to do this, but I am having problems when I need to jump length of the word in list. I am taking lenght of word and then I need to add the words that come previously in the list till this word. This is where I am getting error.

```
song = ["Es", "gingen", "zwei", "Parallelen",
"ins", "Endlose", "hinaus",
"zwei", "kerzengerade", "Seelen",
"und", "aus", "solidem", "Haus",

"Sie", "wollten", "sich", "nicht", "schneiden",
"bis", "an", "ihr", "seliges", "Grab",
"Das", "war", "nun", "einmal", "der", "beiden",
"geheimer", "Stolz", "und", "Stab",

"Doch", "als", "sie", "zehn", "Lichtjahre",
"gewandert", "neben", "sich", "hin", #hin[42]
"da", "wards", "dem", "einsamen", "Paare",
"nicht", "irdisch", "mehr", "zu", "Sinn",

"Warn", "sie", "noch", "Parallelen",
"Sie", "wußtens", "selber", "nicht", 
"sie", "flossen", "nur", "wie", "zwei", "Seelen",
"zusammen", "durch", "ewiges", "Licht",

"Das", "ewige", "Licht", "durchdrang", "sie",
"da", "wurden", "sie", "eins", "in", "ihm",
"die", "Ewigkeit", "verschlang", "sie",
"als", "wie", "zwei", "Seraphim"]

word = input("Enter a word")

if word in song[0:43]:
    print(word)
    a = song[len(word)+song[0:word]]
    print(a)
```

Comment: `len(word)+song[0:word]` attempts to add the integer returned by `len` and a list produced by `song[0:word]`, which is not possible

Comment: how do i make song[0:word] just count the words? That is what I need

Comment: Can you give us an example of how it would work after the first step? It goes to `es` then `+2` to `zwei` and then it looks through the list for `zwei` or for `es`?

Comment: Then it takes length of "zwei" and lands by "hinaus". But the problem is also, that "zwei" appears 2 times and when the input is "zwei" program doesn't know where to start... omg I just realized this ..:(

Comment: Would request if you can put more detail in your question above. I am a bit confused as what exactly you need. (first/second half of the song? Input word?, which word do you wanna count? etc). it will help if you can explain in step by step detail of what you need to do

Comment: Can you show an example of the outut you want?

Comment: Input: "Es" len of this word is 2. Output:"zwei", "hinaus", "solidem", "schneiden", "einmal", "Stab", "zehn", "sich", "dem", "nicht", "Warn", "Sie", "nicht", "zwei", "ewiges", "sie", "sie", "ihm", "verschlang", and now we come to the end of the list and word "Es" doesn't appear in the list anymore. The task is to take a word out of the first half of the song, and see if it appears in the second half again, but we have to do it in a specific way. We take the length of the word and jump that many times to word2 and then take length of the word 2 and jump that many times to word3...

Comment: Since "solidem" is 7 letters, shouldn't the next word be "bis"?

Comment: You are right, I am sorry. I am tired already, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure where you're having a problem, but based on the initial description, you can use the `index` function of a list to determine the location of a value.

Then you can increment the value of index by the length of the word found there.

Before adding the found value to the list, check if it already exists there and - if it does - skip it.

```
song = ["Es", "gingen", "zwei", "Parallelen",
"ins", "Endlose", "hinaus",
"zwei", "kerzengerade", "Seelen",
"und", "aus", "solidem", "Haus",

"Sie", "wollten", "sich", "nicht", "schneiden",
"bis", "an", "ihr", "seliges", "Grab",
"Das", "war", "nun", "einmal", "der", "beiden",
"geheimer", "Stolz", "und", "Stab",

"Doch", "als", "sie", "zehn", "Lichtjahre",
"gewandert", "neben", "sich", "hin", #hin[42]
"da", "wards", "dem", "einsamen", "Paare",
"nicht", "irdisch", "mehr", "zu", "Sinn",

"Warn", "sie", "noch", "Parallelen",
"Sie", "wußtens", "selber", "nicht", 
"sie", "flossen", "nur", "wie", "zwei", "Seelen",
"zusammen", "durch", "ewiges", "Licht",

"Das", "ewige", "Licht", "durchdrang", "sie",
"da", "wurden", "sie", "eins", "in", "ihm",
"die", "Ewigkeit", "verschlang", "sie",
"als", "wie", "zwei", "Seraphim"]

#word = input("Enter a word")
word = "zwei" # The input
found_list = [] # The list for found words
index = song.index(word) # Get the index of the first instance of "word"
while True: # Keep running until "break"
    try: # This will throw an error when index is out of range
        # If the word at index is not already in found_list, add it
        if song[index] not in found_list: 
            found_list.append(song[index])
        # regardless of whether you add the found word, 
        # increment the index by the length of the found word
        index += len(song[index]) 
    except: 
        break

print(found_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['zwei', 'hinaus', 'solidem', 'bis', 'seliges', 'beiden', 'als', 'Lichtjahre', 'nicht', 'Warn', 'Sie', 'ewiges', 'sie', 'ihm', 'verschlang']
```